# Force Flex Datagrid to scroll

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

Is there a way to make the datagrid scroll if it's width exceeds it's parent container (instead of making the parent container scroll?)

I have a datagrid with a fixed column, and of course I want the scrollbar to appear for the datagrid and not the enclosing HBox.

I already set minWidth of the HBox to 0, tried autoLayout=false, but with no effects.

The datagrid is dynamically created in AS3, so the enclosing container.

Thx,
martin

Maybe I did not express my needs clearly - the content of the datagrid should not be wider than the datagrid itself. I just want to surrounding Canvas of the Datagrid to not have any scrollbars and let the datagrid itself scroll. But just setting the scrollpolicy to off on the Canvas will not yield to scrollbars on the datagrid, it will rather clip the data.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the horizontal scroll policy of the parent container to no, but I'm not sure what you want is really possible, You are asking the content of the datagrid to be wider than the datagrid itself is. You are better off using the horizontal scroll from the container and leaving enough room below the datagrid for the scroll bar.